# jQuery Ajax success callback on failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax post request with success, failure and status code handlers. However, when the request fails with a 400 error, part of the success function is still called. Could someone please tell me why?

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: saveToGetTalentUrl.url,
        data: JSON.stringify(candidateList),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#save_to_getTalent").replaceWith("Saved to getTalent");
            alert("New User " + response.candidate.full_name + " created successfully");
            console.log(msg);
            //normalExec(response, msg);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {

            console.log(errormessage);
        },
        statusCode: {
            400:function(){
                alert(errors.err400);
            },
            401:function(){
                alert(errors.err401);
            },
            403:function(){
                alert(errors.err403);
            },
            500:function(){
                alert(errors.err500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When the call fails with a 400 error, the error from statusCode is displayed and the error is logged from the error function, but at the same time, the line `$("#save_to_getTalent").replaceWith("Saved to getTalent");` is also called. I dont understand why

Comment: whether the `alert` after that is getting called?

Comment: no, none of the other lines in the success function are executed. only the .replaceWith line is

Comment: One way to make sure the success is getting called is to remove that line from the success handler... then see whether the changes is happening after the ajax.. if so then some other code is doing it

Comment: this is the only instance of this line in the entire script so it cant be called from anywhere else?

Comment: I'm guessing that `response.candidate.full_name` cannot be resolved because either `response` or `candidate` is undefined. In that case, it's normal that the code breaks and goes no further than the replaceWith. Do you get any error at all in the console?

Comment: response.candidate.full_name is always available. its part of the argument json recieved by the function. 
The error i recieve is a 400 bad request error. the console logs it. but no other unexpected error

Answer (score 1):

Try set `async: true` to see what happens.

See this part in the jQuery documentation for `ajax`:

> async (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

So, the request by default (`async: true`) are sent one by one, not all together. If the POST takes a while, you may see the callback function executed **before** the POST request returned completely. When the first line of `success` is executed, it is blocked because you have a dialog popped up; meanwhile, the `statusCode` part is also executed; it continues to the end because nothing is blocking there.

Debug with a dialog is not the best solution because it always blocks; you can try to change some element's value to see the execute order, like changing an `<input>`'s value, append a number to see if the whole number string changes or not, to see if there is a race condition of `success` and  `statusCode`.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    data:
    url:
    success: function(returned, status, xhr) {
        $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "1");
    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "2");
    },
    statusCode: {
        400:function(){
            $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "3");
        },
        401:function(){
            $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "4");
        },
        403:function(){
            $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "5");
        },
        500:function(){
            $('#testInput').val($('#testInput').val() + "6");
        }
    }
});
```